# Grothendieck 's question - any update?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-topology

I was reading Barry Mazur's [biography](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/%7Ehistory/Biographies/Mazur_Barry.html) and come across this part:

*Grothendieck was exceptionally patient with me, for when we first met I knew next to nothing about algebra. In one of his first conversations with me, he raised the question (asked of him by Washnitzer) of whether a smooth proper algebraic variety defined over a real quadratic field could yield topologically different differentiable manifolds realized by the two possible imbeddings of the number field into the reals. What a perfect question, at least for me! Not that I answered it. But it was surely one of the very few algebro-geometric questions that I then had the background to appreciate. ... the question provided quite an incentive for a topologist to look at algebraic geometry. I began to learn the elements of algebraic geometry working with Mike Artin.*

Is the problem still open? I am an algebraic topology student so it feels very surprising someone will come up with a question like this. But I am at a loss how to experimentally find some toy examples one can work by hand.

Comment: Dear user, There are examples of varieties defined over number fields which give non-homeomorphic manifolds for different embeddings of the number field into $\mathbb C$.  I think that Serre gave one of the first such examples, and the theory of Shimura varieties provides others.  If I can recall the details, I'll post an answer.  I'm not sure if I can give an example defined over a real quad. field, though; I'll have to think about it.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Emerton: I see. I should ask my professor (Adrian Vasiu) next semester.

Comment: Dear user, Yes, Adrian will know many examples, probably off the top of his head! Regards,

Comment: Dear Emerton: You know him! Yes, he is very quick and is usually correct.

Comment: Dear user, Yes, I know him; we work in the same field (roughly speaking).  Regards,

Comment: Dear Emerton: I have met Professor Vasiu, and he said he cannot recall such an example right away. He said this is just taking quotients of schimura varieties in a subtle way. My level is too low to appreciate his explanation, so the question remains open (to me).

Comment: Doesn't an elliptic curve with non totally positive discriminant work (as mention in this [post](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/topology-that-algebra-cant-see/) you pointed out in [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129059/grothendieck-s-question-any-update)) ?

Comment: That one only handles the imaginary case, as you can see. I suspect real quadratic fields are more difficult in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just noticed this hanging (?) question: depending on what is wanting, maybe the following is worthwhile...

How about the variety that is a quaternion division algebra $B$ over a real quadratic extension $k$ of $\mathbb Q$ which splits at one real place and not the other. Then the norm-one group at one of the real places is compact, and the other isn't.

Now, yes, there is a clear causal mechanism for such an example, and maybe that's not what's desired...

Answer (score 9):

Since this question has been hanging around for a few years, I think I should post Prof. Mazur's official answer below:

---

Hello Bombyx mori,

Take a look at

J.-P. Serre, Exemples de variétés projectives conjuguées non homéomorphes, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 258 (1964), 4194-4196.

which actually gives two conjugate algebraic varieties with different fundamental groups, and therefore different homotopy types.

Best wishes,

Barry Mazur

---

I received the email about one year ago and forget to post it, as I am no longer active at the site. This is in fact the source of David Speyer's [blog post](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/topology-that-algebra-cant-see/), so it is well known already. Whether the real quadratic case is closed I am still not sure (as I am not an expert on number fields), but hopefully this gives fellow mathematicans some encouragement to read Serre's [original paper](https://books.google.com/books?id=gvcn0vT8X1QC&pg=PA246&lpg=PA246&dq=Exemple%20de%20vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9s%20projectives%20conjugu%C3%A9es%20non%20hom%C3%A9omorphes&source=bl&ots=HI5qrQCUKE&sig=ilj4N9AR1xtHaqVvnQL3ViMJkH8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV2Ke62cDKAhUBs4MKHXFvCEIQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Exemple%20de%20vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9s%20projectives%20conjugu%C3%A9es%20non%20hom%C3%A9omorphes&f=false). What Prof. Vasiu was refering to should be something similar to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1953).

Comment: The paper is also available [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4011c/f1832.item).

Answer (score 2):

One interpretation of the question is the following. Let $X$ be a smooth proper algebraic variety over a real quadratic number field $K$. Let $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ be the two embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbf R$. Denote by $X(\mathbf{R}_i)$ the set of real points of $X$ with respect to the embedding $\sigma_i$ of $K$ into $\mathbf R$. Can it happen that $X(\mathbf{R}_1)$ and $X(\mathbf{R}_2)$ are not homeomorphic?

It is quite easy to construct elementary examples of such varieties. Consider quadrics in projective $n$-space $\mathrm{P}^n$, for example. For $n=2$ you have the nonsingular conic $C$ defined by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2\sqrt2=0$ over the real quadratic number field $K=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt2)$. If you map $\sqrt2\in K$ to the positive square root of $2$ in $\mathbf R$ then the set of real points of $C$ will be the empty differentiable manifold of dimension $1$. If you map $\sqrt2\in K$ to the negative square root of $2$ in $\mathbf R$ then the set of real points of $C$ will be diffeomorphic to the circle $S^1$. They are certainly not homeomorphic.

In higher dimension one can obtain more interesting examples. For $n=3$ one can consider the nonsingular quadric $Q$ defined by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2\sqrt2-w^2=0$ in $\mathbf{P}^3$ over $K$. With respect to the first embedding of $K$ into $\mathbf R$, the set of real points of $Q$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere $S^2$. With respect to the second, the set of real points of $Q$ is diffeomorphic to the torus $S^1\times S^1$. Again, they are not homeomorphic.